# mosaic.map is not a function

Tags: google-earth-engine, javascript, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to find NDVI of cropland that I have masked from ESA and mosaiced it with Sentinel but I'm facing error of mosaic.map is not a function when I try to find NDVI map and NDVI chart for cropland. I don't know why it is giving me error when my first code is running fine.

```
Map.centerObject(aoi)
var s2 = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2');
var s2c = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S2_CLOUD_PROBABILITY');

var start = ee.Date('2017-06-15');
var end = ee.Date('2017-10-15');

function filterBoundsDate(imgCol, aoi, start, end) {
  return imgCol.filterBounds(aoi).filterDate(start, end)}
s2 = filterBoundsDate(s2, aoi, start, end);
s2c = filterBoundsDate(s2c, aoi, start, end);

function indexJoin(colA, colB, propName) {
  var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveFirst(propName).apply({
    primary: colA,
    secondary: colB,
    condition: ee.Filter.equals(
        {leftField: 'system:index', rightField: 'system:index'})
  }));
  return joined.map(function(image) {
    return image.addBands(ee.Image(image.get(propName)));
  });
}

function buildMaskFunction(cloudProb) {
  return function(img) {
    var cloud = img.select('probability').gt(ee.Image(cloudProb));

    return img.updateMask(cloud.not());
  };
}

var withCloudProbability = indexJoin(s2, s2c, 'cloud_probability');

var maskClouds = buildMaskFunction(50);
var s2Masked = ee.ImageCollection(withCloudProbability.map(maskClouds))
                   .select(ee.List.sequence(0, 12));

var median = s2Masked.median();

var difFromMedian = s2Masked.map(function(img) {
  var dif = ee.Image(img).subtract(median).pow(ee.Image.constant(2));
  return dif.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum()).addBands(img).copyProperties(img, [
    'system:time_start'
  ]);
});


var bandNames = difFromMedian.first().bandNames();
var bandPositions = ee.List.sequence(1, bandNames.length().subtract(1));
var mosaic = difFromMedian.reduce(ee.Reducer.min(bandNames.length()))
                 .select(bandPositions, bandNames.slice(1))
                 .clipToCollection(aoi);
Map.addLayer(
    mosaic, {bands: ['B11', 'B8', 'B3'], min: 225, max: 4000}, 'S2 mosaic');
    




var hansenImage = ee.ImageCollection("ESA/WorldCover/v100").first();

var datamask = hansenImage.select('datamask');

var classification = hansenImage.select('Map').clip(aoi)
var mask = classification.eq(40)

var visParams = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 0.3};

var maskedComposite = mosaic.updateMask(mask);
Map.addLayer(maskedComposite, visParams, 'masked');
var crop = mask.not();
crop = crop.mask(crop);
var mosaic = ee.ImageCollection([
  median.visualize(visParams),
  crop.visualize({palette: '000044'}),
]).mosaic();
Map.addLayer(mosaic.clip(aoi), {}, 'custom mosaic');

var addNDVI = function(image) {
return image.addBands(image.normalizedDifference(['B5', 'B4']));
};

var l8 = mosaic.map(addNDVI)
var NDVI = l8.select(['nd']);
var NDVImed = NDVI.median(); 
var ndviVis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1,
  palette: [
    'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
    '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
    '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
  ],
};
Map.addLayer(ndvi.clip(aoi),ndviVis, 'NDVI');

var plotNDVI = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(s2, aoi,ee.Reducer.mean(),'nd',30,'system:time_start', 'system:index')
```

the script link is:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/9f9dff57ccac431a25a4a45033cef323

Answer (score 0):

You can not map over a single image. After you calculated the median of your collection, you receive only one image and `.map` only works with an image collection. When you try to calculate the median of a Region use the function `ee.Image.reduceRegion`.

Comment: Yes you are right. what if I want to apply on image collection? because I want to generate time series chart of NDVI for cropland masked from ESA.